# Adding sub directory to an existing path

Tags: java, file

I have an existing directory with files in it.Is it possible to add a sub directory in between the path?
For eg:I have a path ***MyProject/com/st/abc.java***
Is it possible to add a directory before /com
ie ***MyProject/src/com/st/abc.java***?
I want to achieve the above using java.

```
public static void createSrcDirectory(File folder) throws SecurityException, Exception{

        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                createSrcDirectory(fileEntry);
            } else {

                String filePath = fileEntry.getAbsolutePath();
                 int index =filePath.indexOf(Constants.srcDir);
                 StringBuilder s =new StringBuilder(filePath);
                 if (index ==-1){
                    index =s.indexOf(Constants.comDir);
                    if(index !=-1){
                    s.insert(index,Constants.srcDir);
                    File file =new File(s.toString());
                    file.mkdirs();
                    }
                 }
            }   
        }
    }
```

This creates a new folder `src`  altogether.I wanted the same to be added to the existing path.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Please read through [ask] and [help]. You must show some effort that you at least tried. Then come back with a more specific question, like if you have trouble with a specific step of the task. Also you must research. I'm sure you'll find plenty of questions on the various sub-problems of this task. Like how to copy a directory to a different place and how to create a new directory etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks basic research or any other sort of effort.

Comment: The tasks are: Create a new directory `src` in `MyProject`. Then move the directory `com` to the newly created `src`. Make sure to move (or copy & delete). That's it. Google for those 2-3 sub-steps and you'll quickly find solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, create the new directory

```
new File("MyProject/src").mkdir();
```

Then move everything below that into your new directory

```
Files.move(Paths.get("MyProject/com"), Paths.get("MyProject/src/com"));
```

Can't test right now, but it should put you on the right track at least

Comment: Is there a particular reason you use the old outdated `File` API instead of the newer modern NIO (`Files`, `Paths`, `Path`) for the first part?

Comment: @Zabuza no particular reason, no.